# How to monitor which files lots of data is being written to on Linux?

Tags: linux, monitoring, io, disk-monitoring

I can monitor I/O with tools such as iotop. It allows me to identify which processes do how much I/O.

Now I'd like to know which files those processes write all that data to. How would I do that?

E.g. something like "ok I know Tomcat is doing a lot of I/O. Which files is it mostly reading/writing from/to"?

Comment: Doesn't `iotop -o` give you that information?

Comment: Not that I see. It gives me the processes/threads, and the total stats, but not the names of the files.

Answer (score 14):

I know two ways to get that kind of information.

1. Manually using `lsof`.
   The good old `lsof` can show you what files are being accessed by a process or thread, along with a few other pieces of information. In `iotop -o`, eyeball and take note of the `TID` (Thread ID) value of the process or thread you need to inspect. Then close `iotop` and run `lsof -p [pid/tid]`. If you need to sort the output, pipe it to `sort`. For example, `lsof -p [pid or tid] | sort -n -k 7,7 -r` will sort the output from `lsof` by the seventh column (`SIZE/OFF`) in reverse order (biggest to smallest).
2. Using `fatrace`.
   This new addition to Linux is similar to `inotify`, except it doesn't target specific files/directories. It shows you aggregate disk I/O based on files being accessed. Depending on your distribution, you might or might not have access to this nifty little program in precompiled executable form. The oldest distribution that provides `fatrace` in its official repositories that I know of is Ubuntu 12.04. Debian 7, which I'm using, doesn't have it.

Comment: These seem to tell me which files my process accesses, but doesn't tell me which of those files are the ones that all the data is being written to. The "size" in lsof seems to be the file size, NOT the rate at which the process writes into the file. And I don't see anything related to size/rate in http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/fatrace.1.html at all.

Comment: fatrace is perfect.  Put it in the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

csysdig is probably your best bet. It has a nice ncurses interface.
https://github.com/draios/sysdig/wiki/Csysdig-Overview